# backendless app crash after its first use

Tags: ios, objective-c, backendless

i tried to use backendless as my backend, and i read the documentation i used their sample codes, when i run my app it crashes with following error

> backendlessTest[9984:8668361] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception of class 'Fault' libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type Fault
>       (lldb)

my code is

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Backendless.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    BackendlessUser *user = [BackendlessUser new];
    user.email = @"rawandahmad698@gmail.com";
    user.password = @"mypassisHidden";
    [backendless.userService registering:user];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the error handling page of the docs:
https://backendless.com/documentation/users/ios/users_error_handling.htm

Specifically add a try/catch block and make sure to handle a scenario when an error is thrown. The error will contain the details on what went wrong.